# How to change my PCI bridge? Using Intel Xeon Graphics instead of Nvidia GTX

Tags: nvidia, intel, pcie

First of all I'd like to say that I'm new to Ubuntu (former Windows user), so this might be a noob question. By the way, I was trying to play Rocket League using Heroic Games Launcher, but the performance is awful. I am sure that I am using my Intel Integrated Graphics instead of my Nvidia GPU. Here my overall specs:

Intel i5 8500 3 GHz
GTX 1060 6gb
16gb RAM 2666 (2x8)

In Windows, I can use Rocket League Maximum Graphics with stable +85 fps, and in Ubuntu I never get more than 15 fps. When I open System Monitor, for some reason, I don't see the GPU. So, I googled how to see my PCI connections, and I see this

`lspci -v`

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 8th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 07)
    DeviceName: Onboard - Other
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd 8th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: skl_uncore
    Kernel modules: ie31200_edac

00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor PCIe Controller (x16) (rev 07) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 121
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=01, subordinate=01, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 00004000-00004fff [size=4K]
    Memory behind bridge: a2000000-a30fffff [size=17M]
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 0000000090000000-00000000a1ffffff [size=288M]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:12.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH Thermal Controller (rev 10)
    DeviceName: Onboard - Other
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd Cannon Lake PCH Thermal Controller
    Flags: fast devsel, IRQ 16
    Memory at a341c000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: intel_pch_thermal
    Kernel modules: intel_pch_thermal

00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH USB 3.1 xHCI Host Controller (rev 10) (prog-if 30 [XHCI])
    DeviceName: Onboard - Other
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd Cannon Lake PCH USB 3.1 xHCI Host Controller
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 126
    Memory at a3400000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd
    Kernel modules: xhci_pci

00:14.2 RAM memory: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH Shared SRAM (rev 10)
    DeviceName: Onboard - Other
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH Shared SRAM
    Flags: fast devsel
    Memory at a3416000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [disabled] [size=8K]
    Memory at a341b000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [disabled] [size=4K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>

00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH HECI Controller (rev 10)
    DeviceName: Onboard - Other
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd Cannon Lake PCH HECI Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 124
    Memory at a341a000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: mei_me

00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH SATA AHCI Controller (rev 10) (prog-if 01 [AHCI 1.0])
    DeviceName: Onboard - SATA
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd Cannon Lake PCH SATA AHCI Controller
    Flags: bus master, 66MHz, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 125
    Memory at a3414000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=8K]
    Memory at a3419000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256]
    I/O ports at 5030 [size=8]
    I/O ports at 5020 [size=4]
    I/O ports at 5000 [size=32]
    Memory at a3418000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=2K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: ahci

00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH PCI Express Root Port #5 (rev f0) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 122
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=02, subordinate=02, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: [disabled]
    Memory behind bridge: a3300000-a33fffff [size=1M]
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: [disabled]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH PCI Express Root Port #9 (rev f0) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 123
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=03, subordinate=03, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 00003000-00003fff [size=4K]
    Memory behind bridge: a3200000-a32fffff [size=1M]
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: [disabled]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Device a308 (rev 10)
    DeviceName: Onboard - Other
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd Device 5001
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0

00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH cAVS (rev 10)
    DeviceName: Onboard - Sound
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd Cannon Lake PCH cAVS
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 32, IRQ 129
    Memory at a3410000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Memory at a3100000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1M]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel, snd_sof_pci_intel_cnl

00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH SMBus Controller (rev 10)
    DeviceName: Onboard - Other
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd Cannon Lake PCH SMBus Controller
    Flags: medium devsel, IRQ 16
    Memory at a3418800 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256]
    I/O ports at efa0 [size=32]
    Kernel driver in use: i801_smbus
    Kernel modules: i2c_i801

00:1f.5 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH SPI Controller (rev 10)
    DeviceName: Onboard - Other
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH SPI Controller
    Flags: fast devsel
    Memory at fe010000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Kernel driver in use: intel-spi
    Kernel modules: intel_spi_pci

01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP106 [GeForce GTX 1060 6GB] (rev a1) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] GP106 [GeForce GTX 1060 6GB]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 255
    Memory at a2000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
    Memory at 90000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    Memory at a0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=32M]
    I/O ports at 4000 [size=128]
    Expansion ROM at 000c0000 [disabled] [size=128K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau

01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation GP106 High Definition Audio Controller (rev a1)
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] GP106 High Definition Audio Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 17
    Memory at a3080000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
```

Isn't my PCI bridge supposed to be controlled by Nvidia?
How do I change it?

Comment: As written, this is an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378). Always ask about the actual problem that you face. Provide details about that problem.  You should describe the exact steps needed to reproduce the problem and describe the problem exactly as it manifests. In this case, you are asking about a proposed solution that is not anything you can change and won't solve your problem. You've provided details about this proposed solution, instead of details about the problem. As written this question is unanswerable

Comment: According to the steam product page, Rocket League only has a Windows client. Linux/Ubuntu cannot run Windows games natively. You would need to use a VM or compatibility layer like Wine.  Software on a VM or Wine will not perform as well as it would perform on a native client, especially for online/competitive games. Search results appear to indicate that Rocket League used to have support on Mac and Linux and the game devs stopped supporting those platforms. If this is true, suggest that you complain to the software devs for dropping support.

Comment: Sorry for not being specific... I put Rocket League as an example, but my main question is how to change my pci configs, because I think I am not using my gtx 1060. The RL performance is what lead me to this awareness. I used it as context.

Comment: To start with we should know your OS & release details. Sure you mention Ubuntu, but haven't said what product, what release, or if you're using a LTS release which kernel stack you've chosen (*this is optional but as we don't know your release this maybe significant as games usually perform better on the newer stack option*). Providing the product & release details is a start. Your paste has many *access denied* messages; use `sudo` to elevate privileges to avoid this.  *eg. Are you using Ubunu Core? Ubuntu Server? Ubuntu Desktop etc.. we may guess desktop but it's best if we're not guessing*

Comment: You can't change your PCI Bridge. It's a component soldered to your motherboard. Again, ask about the actual problem, not your proposed solution.  Trying to enable a GPU when you aren't even sure if it's already enabled is also a proposed solution.  It doesn't really describe the problem.  Is this a laptop with hybrid graphics or is this a desktop with a truly dedicated GPU? `lspci` is showing Nvidia as the VGA controller so I'm not sure that you are correct in the theory that it's not enabled. Are you using proprietary drivers or nouveau?

Comment: If your problem is poorer performance running Windows-only games on Ubuntu compared to Windows, your problem might not have a solution, but an explanation

Comment: How did you install the graphics drivers for the NVIDIA card?  Also, unless the game is optimized for Linux it will not work as expected when ran in Windows.

Comment: Have you read this Q/A? https://askubuntu.com/questions/61396/how-do-i-install-the-nvidia-drivers